# Instance Variables in a Class Method (inccessable)

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a class from what was previously a view controller.  It just contains some database set-up calls.  In my research I discovered that I was receiving a "No known class for method..." error because I had not defined the class method properly.  Heres what I had:

```
View1.m
...
[view2 databseBuild];
...

classA.h
-(void)databaseBuild;

classA.m
 -(void)databaseBuild
       {
         ...
        }
```

This is what I changed my class to:

```
classA.h
    +(void)databaseBuild;

  classA.m

    +(void)databaseBuild
      {
        ...
       }
```

However, what I am receiving now is a boatload of error. All of them basically around instance variable not 'variable" accessed in class method.  Is there a "best practice" for creating classes to avoid this type of error?

Comment: How are you calling these methods?

Comment: You simply can't access instance variables in a class method -- there's no instance available through which you could get them. Can you elaborate on what you're doing? Maybe include the contents of these methods?

Answer (score 0):

for objective-c methods

```
- (void)method {}
```

will create a instance method that can be used as follows:

```
MyClass *instance = [MyClass alloc] init];
[instance method]
```

While the other hand

```
+ (void)method {}
```

will create a class method that can be called with:

```
[MyClass method]
```

The errors that you are receiving due to the fact that there no such things as Class variables in objective-c (but you can create static variables in the global scope as a workaround)

Comment: Generally Class methods are used as Factory methods to returned autoreleased instance objects.

Answer (score 0):

`+(void)databaseBuild;` is a class method. You call it with `[MyClass databaseBuild];`. Class methods are methods that work independent of an object. For example `[NSArray arrayWithObject:]` is a class method.

`-(void)databaseBuild;` is an instance method. You call it with `[myClassInstance databaseBuild];` It is mostly used to interact with the object instance. (e.g. `[myArray objectAtIndex:]`)

You said you were using `[view2 databseBuild];` which is a call to an instance method.

Most likely it would have been enough to #import the header file into the file where you tried to use [view1 databaseBuild].

Your boatload of errors probably tell you that you can't access instance variables or @properties from a class method.